# Labels are not aligned properly with text box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have the following code on my page:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <label asp-for="id"  class=" control-label " style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
                <input asp-for="id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for=id" class="text-danger"></span>
         </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
              <label class=" control-label " style="font-weight:bold;">OR</label>
          </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
                <label asp-for="EmailAddress"  class=" control-label " style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
                <input asp-for="EmailAddress" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EmailAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
         </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                 <label class=" control-label " style="font-weight:bold;">OR</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label asp-for="Customer" class=" control-label " style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
                <input asp-for="Customer" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Customer" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
              
            </div>
         </div>
```

when I run the code, [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dnWX.png)

I am trying to align the "OR" in the middle. I don't want "OR" to be floating at the top like it shows in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pressume you are using bootstrap

I also fixed asp-validation-for attribute, please always check your markup

Just align the `or` tags

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label asp-for="id" class=" control-label " style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
    <input asp-for="id" class="form-control" />
    <!-- fixed asp-validation-for attribute -->
    <span asp-validation-for="id" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <!-- Align the tags -->
  <div class="col-md-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <label class="control-label " style="font-weight:bold;">OR</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label asp-for="EmailAddress" class=" control-label " style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
    <input asp-for="EmailAddress" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="EmailAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <label class=" control-label " style="font-weight:bold;">OR</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label asp-for="Customer" class=" control-label " style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
    <input asp-for="Customer" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Customer" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">

  </div>
</div>
```